# Simultaneous approximation of polynomial system's roots

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, numerical-methods

To find a root of a polynomial in one variable, it is possible to use Newton's method. It is simple and fast, but which exact root is going to be found depends on the initial guess and so it is difficult to find all the roots.

There are several generalizations of Newton's method which are able to approximate all the roots simultaneously by employing the so-called Weierstrass correction, for example Durand-Kerner's or Aberth's methods.

For systems of $n$ multivariate polynomial equations in $n$ variables  there exists another generalization of Newton's method which allows one to find a root (i.e. a set of values where the system becomes zero). It uses Jacobian matrix.

Please, does anyone know of a method which simultaneously approximates all the solutions of such a multivariate polynomial system? Kind of like Durand-Kerner which uses Jacobian in the corrections, instead of Newton? By sheer luck, does anyone know of an implementation of such algorithm?

Comment: The zeros of a single polynomial in $n$ variables usually form an $n-1$-dimensional variety, not a finite set, so how do you expect to "simultaneously approximate all the solutions"?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I apologize, I'm not sure if I understand: I meant system of n polynomials in n variables. So if both polynomials have highest power of three, I would like to find all 9 solutions, so the initial approximation would have 9 distinct values.

Comment: @Moo Those links deal with univariate polynomial, whereas the question is about multivariate case.

Comment: If you meant a system, you should say so.  Please edit your question.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Done, I hope it's now less confusing...